# Script runs properly in command line, but not through key shortcut (Xournal, xdotool)

Tags: bash

I am writing a small script to allow me to toggle between the pen (CTRL+SHIFT+P) and highlighter (CTRL+SHIFT+H) of Xournal.  I wrote a script that uses a config file to record the last state of the stylus, read that state, and change it to the alternate stylus state; all of this can then be mapped to one key.  I've tested this script thoroughly using command line (in the Terminal) and it works fine.  When I assign a shortcut key to trigger the script however, the toggle doesn't work.

The config file "Last Modified" timestamp updates whether I run the script through the terminal or through the shortcut key.

I've been racking my brain trying to get this to work.  The script is attached.

```
#/bin/bash
# Script to make stylus tips toggle between pen and highlighter as well as color

TOGGLE_FILE=/home/mustafa/bin/toggle.config
source $TOGGLE_FILE
HIGHLIGHTER_KEYWORD="hi"
PEN_KEYWORD="pen"

# Conditions to switch toggle state from highligther to pen or vice versa
if [ $TOGGLE_STATE = $PEN_KEYWORD ]; then
    xdotool key "control+shift+H"
    TOGGLE_STATE=$HIGHLIGHTER_KEYWORD
else
    xdotool key "control+shift+P"
    TOGGLE_STATE=$PEN_KEYWORD
fi

# Replaces the toggle file with new toggle state
echo "TOGGLE_STATE=\"$TOGGLE_STATE\"" > $TOGGLE_FILE
notify-send "$(echo $(cat $TOGGLE_FILE))"
```

Comment: consider adding a tag for the OS you're using and the hardware platform... "assign a shortcut key" , could be anything from an Atari to a Cray ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Details of your shortcut ?

Comment: It is ctrl+alt+backspace which invokes the script.  The script is in ~/bin.

Comment: You waste two processes and a disk round-trip with `$(echo $(cat file))` where the `echo` is completely wasteful and the `cat` could simply be replaced with the values you just wrote into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add quotation here:

```
if [ "$TOGGLE_STATE" = "$PEN_KEYWORD" ]; then
```

and also: 
    "$TOGGLE_FILE"

```
full/path/here/xdotool
```

Also quick reading of xdotool documentation gave me the impression that events may be ignored by system if they are not generated in terminal.  I'm not sure if you can trick around that problem by invoking a terminal to run the lines starting by "xdotool". In case of gnome-terminal that would be:

```
gnome-terminal -e 'what-ever-command'
```

Comment: I did and it behaves the same way. With the key shortcut it doesn't toggle, with command line it does.